# SeekBar inside a draggable view (SlideHolder)

Tags: android, android-layout

I use a 3rd party component (AndroidSideMenu) which allows the whole activity to be dragged to the right to expose a side menu.

In the main (non-menu) section of the layout I have a horizontal SeekBar.
The problem is that when I start dragging the SeekBar button, the whole layout drags along with it because the SlideHolder component is also responding to the drag events.

I'm not sure how touch events are managed in Android, but is there a way to stop the events after they are processed by the SeekBar so that they don't reach the parent container?
So when you drag the Seekbar, the whole screen (parent) must stay put, but when you drag outside the SeekBar it must still work as required for the side menu?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the container of the SeekBar, create and apply (to the seekBar) an OnTouchListener like the following:

```
private final OnTouchListener onTouchListener = new OnTouchListener()
{
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {
        // If the View in question isn't a child of the seekBar and
        // isn't the seekBar itself, then return and don't consume the event.
        if ( (seekBar.findViewById(v.getId()) == null) &&
             (v.getId() != seekBar.getId()) )
        {
            return false;
        }

        // The View is either a child of the seekBar or is the seekBar itself,
        // so we pass the event along to the seekBar and return true, signifying
        // that the event has been consumed.
        seekBar.onTouchEvent(event);

        return true;
    }
}
```

Try this out and see if it works; you may need to create a more robust condition for the if statement.